# invalid use of non-static member function when passing function as argument

Tags: c++, function, non-static

Could anyone help me to fix this bug " error: invalid use of non-static member function" in line  *test(3, a.foo);* when i compile the codes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
 public:
  int x = 0;
  void foo(int y){
   x = x + y;    
  }
};
template<typename Func>
void test(int d, Func f){
  f(d);    
}

int main()
{
  A a;
  a.foo(4);
  std::cout << a.x;
  test(3, a.foo);
}
```

Comment: Just like it says, you can't pass a pointer to a member function where a pointer to an ordinary function is expected.  (Under the hood, a member function typically expects a hidden `this` parameter, and the code for `test` won't know to pass one or what it should be.)  So redesign your program so that it doesn't need to do that.

Comment: Also in future, please always use the tag for the programming language you are asking about.  I added the [tag:c++] tag here, hopefully I'm right.

Comment: use std::bind()